# Linux options for Virtual Monitors?

Tags: linux, display, lg-monitor

A friend was for days talking about how wonderful his new screen will be when it gets delivered. He was all enthusiastic about the ability to divide up the screen into separate sections, when I said that's what windows do, I was being slow to catch on.

Now that he has shown me (remotely) I am well and truly sold on the idea.

What he bought is an LG 40WP95C-W (39.7" 5K x 2K resolution), it came with some software to divide up the screen into separate virtual screens.

I see two ways this might be working:

a) The monitor pretends to be multiple monitors and the operating system drives them individually via Display Port's ability to address multiple screens in a chain. Configuration via USB. This sounds great.

b) The LG software messes about inside the OS. This sounds terrible.

Either way LG don't do a Linux version of this software.

After a bit of DuckDuckGoing I came across the term "Virtual Monitor" and ways of doing all this in software without the need for extra smarts in the screen.

What I don't want is non standard software from god knows who.

I have seen an option which looks X.Org specific, I would have looked at it a few years ago but given Wayland's progress it no longer has the appeal it would have had in the past.

Does anybody know anything about dividing a screen into multiple virtual screens and is this something we will all take for granted in a couple of years time.

Does anybody know if other screen manufacturers have it built in like LG and do any of them work with Linux ?

Comment: On the Wishlist:  Windows -> Power Toys -> Fanzy Zones   - for GNU/Linux

Comment: Do you have a link to that item in a wishlist ?

Comment: In case English is not your first language, I will try to help you out.  I believe that @Hannu is saying that there is a "Power Toys" utility for windows called *Fansy Zones* that does this.  The "wishlist" ***means that it DOES NOT EXIST***.  A quick google search of his exact text "Fanzy Zones - for GNU/Linux" will put you in the middle of alternate solutions.

Comment: Thank you Señor CMasMas for explaining my misunderstanding of the word "Wishlist". I really need to improve my English. Following your suggestion I did a search for "power toys Fancy Zones for GNU/Linux" and found: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/gfzasq/windows_powertoys_fancyzones_linux_alternative/

Comment: Sorry for the high language barrier, gTiles seems as an alternative for Gnome based desktops (i.e. Ubuntu) - https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/ - I'll have to try it out.